# Can I omit calls to a certain library from my stack trace in Visual Studio?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, boost, callstack

When I'm using the C++ boost libraries and I hit a breakpoint, my stack trace when is always flooded with boost calls. Is there a way I can tell visual studio (some compiler flag?) that I don't want to see any boost calls in my call stacks?

Comment: No. That would be an option to get the visual studio debugger to lie to you. You could always write a script to filter out the Boost calls from stack traces that you have copied and pasted from the debugger stack trace window.

Comment: Well, "lie" is such a hard word in this context. I'm also often getting problems in some system-provided function and the first thing I have to do is to walk up until I get to the lowest line in my own code; having a debugger that basically collapses the "boring" hierarchies into lets say a single line wouldn't be a revolution in debugging, but I wouldn't mind having it. Plus, when you click or otherwise explicitely activate such a collapsed block it could still uncollapse it

Comment: Same happens with any framework or class library you use. You see library calls that cooperate with your functions. It helps you to discover when you had naively wrong idea how the library works (and so what your function's responsibility is) or when the library contains a defect. That is you want to defeat the point of stack trace. Why?

Comment: I want it because most often when I'm looking at my stack trace, I'm trying to debug a non-boost-related issue. Boost calls flood my stack trace, sometimes to the point where I can't see far enough back to get the information I need. It would be convenient to be able to turn boost calls off when I'm working on code that's completely unrelated to boost.